# NLTK error when installing using pip command on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pip, nltk

I tried installing nltk using pip on Ubuntu as follows:
pip install nltk

It displays the following message:

```
Collecting nltk
  Downloading nltk-3.2.2.tar.gz (1.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.2MB 124kB/s 
Collecting six (from nltk)
  Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: nltk
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for nltk ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/siddharth/.cache/pip/wheels/42/b5/27/718985cd9719e8a44a405d264d98214c7a607fb65f3a006f28
Successfully built nltk
Installing collected packages: six, nltk
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/siddharth/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/siddharth/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/siddharth/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/home/siddharth/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/siddharth/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/home/siddharth/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/siddharth/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.pyc'
```

The pip version is 9.0.1 and Python version is 2.7.12

Comment: `sudo pip install -U nltk`

Comment: Without sudo, `pip install --user nltk`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the last line:

`IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:`

Try it again, but put `sudo` at the front: `sudo pip install nltk`.